# How to get the boolean output column(by default false )from aggregate activity in data flow in azure datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm getting error when I'm adding the column.i need a column value as false and it should be boolean in the data preview.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve it.
Please ask if anything I missed or any info needed

Comment: can you add sample input and output and share the error

Comment: @Pratik can you please take any two column as sample datA and boolean column is not from source we need to define it and send it like false  and that one we need out put from agregate it by the two columns.

Comment: Please ask if anything required....thanks for your time

Comment: Error : aggregate column should use at least one aggregate

Comment: Thanks for all support ..it's solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aggregate column should use at least one aggregate.
```

In the aggregation transformation, you need to use at least one aggregation function when creating a new column. If you don't use an aggregate function, you may encounter the error mentioned above.

It's better to use a derived column transformation to create a new column after the aggregation transformation. Use the  `toBoolean()` transformation to obtain a Boolean data type column, use s  `toBoolean("False")` to get false as output, as shown below:

[image]

You will get the column data as below:

[image]